# Driving the Gate of an AC MOSFET Switch

Tags: mosfet, ac, switches, gate-driving

I'm designing a bidirectional AC power switch using two source-to-source connected n-channel MOSFETs. Some restrictions apply to the design:

- I want to use only standard components
- The load must be ground connected
- With an open switch no more than a few microamps can flow through the load
- Normally "closed" switch (e.g. at startup)

I was a bit surprised that I could not find an easy way to drive the gates. I came up with the below circuit which works well as long as fast switching is not an issue. But my attempts to find a solution similar to a push-pull topology for a singular DC mosfet switch were not fruitful so far. Any help?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGEyfo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What are *standard components*? What AC voltage are you considering? What frequency? What on-resistance? How fast do you want to switch? Rise/fall times?

Comment: By standard components I mean transistors, diodes, caps... no driving ICs etc. -  50Hz 12V a couple Amps. On resistance single digit mOhm, but that depends mainly on the FET choice doesn't it? A few microseconds time constant would be fine.

Comment: An opto isolator looks like an IC so how do you justify what you mean and, importantly, why place such a restriction on using ICs? An opto could be a photovoltaic opto and that would solve your problem (mainly) so, where do you draw the line?

Comment: Its a learning project for me, and I want to grasp what happens in the circuit and understand the effect of component parameters/specifications. I understand an Optocoupler, but I do not understand what happens inside a sophisticated driving IC

Comment: Do you understand solar cells?

Comment: Not sure how that is relevant but yes?

Comment: [VOM1271](https://www.vishay.com/docs/83469/vom1271.pdf) might appeal to you. It's a bit slow though (like your current circuit).

Comment: Years ago we simply shorted a diode bridge with a SCR to accomplish the same thing. A MOSFET will work just as well.